# Karma: sourcemaps don't work (with my TypeScript build)

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

Following the readme from the [karma-sourcemap-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sourcemap-loader) npm package, I am unable to see TypeScript sourcemaps being observed under Karma.

I have:

1. Installed the dependency, `karma-sourcemap-loader` in my `package.json`
2. Included the preprocessor configuration in my karma configuration:

   ```
   // karma.conf.js 
   module.exports = function(config) {
     config.set({

       preprocessors: {
         'build/**/*.js': ['sourcemap']
       }

     });
   };
   ```

My TypeScript sourcemaps, each of which are sitting side-by-side with the `.js` output files in the `build` directory, are not being respected.

The Karma process has output indicating 404's for all of the `.js.map` files.

Answer (score 0):

While not documented by `karma-sourcemap-loader`, I had to include the following in my `files` array of the karma configuration:

```
{
    pattern: 'build/**/*.js.map',
    included: false
}
```

Of course, my files are all under a `build` directory, and yours might not be.

**To be clear,** to fix the situation, my "example" karma configuration had to look something like this:

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        files: [
            "build/**/*.js",
            {
                pattern: 'build/**/*.js.map',
                included: false
            }
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            "build/**/*.js": ["sourcemap"]
        }

    });
};
```

The relevant part being, that I needed to include the weird object in the files array.